# Python Requests response 400 Client Error

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to make a request to an API. Information on the actual API is private, so I have to obfuscate my post. The request works in postman, but when I copied the code from postman to vscode, it does not work:

```
url = "https://myapi.com/v1/search"
payload = json.dumps({
    'username': 'user',
    'start_date' : '01/01/2023T16:06:40+00:00',
    'end_date' : '01/02/2023T16:06:40+00:00'
})
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXX',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.post( url, headers=headers, data=payload)
response.raise_for_status()
print(response.json())
```

Error:

```
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error:  for url: https://myapi.com/v1/search
```

However, the request works when I use the http.client library:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("myapi.com")
payload = json.dumps({
    'username': 'user',
    'start_date' : '01/01/2023T16:06:40+00:00',
    'end_date' : '01/02/2023T16:06:40+00:00'
})
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXX',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
conn.request("POST", "/v1/search", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(res.getcode())
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

I can't seem to figure out why. Things I have tried:

- Adding the payload to the json keyword within the request, `requests.post( url, headers=headers, json=payload)`
- Adding `{"User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.30.0"}` within the headers
- `verify=False` within the request
- Also tried requests.Session:

```
s = requests.Session()
url = "https://myapi.com/v1/search"
s.headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXX',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
payload = json.dumps({
    'username': 'user',
    'start_date' : '01/01/2023T16:06:40+00:00',
    'end_date' : '01/02/2023T16:06:40+00:00'
})
response = s.post( url, data=payload)
response.raise_for_status()
print(response.json())
```

Any help is appreciated!

Python = 3.9.7

Requests = 2.28.1

Comment: Instead of `json` have you tried `data`. The other thing is to try creating a session with requests as with http.client.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I forgot to mention I tried Session as well, I will modify the post to reflect it

Comment: I suspect there's some messy thing with Proxy, VPN and stuffs. I also once had no issue with Postman, but had issues when I pasted it to VSCode. Turned out it was the Proxy policies. Have you tried contacting the IT department regarding this? I know it sounds weird but it happened to me.